# Using a '.' in your key name in MongoDB (PyMongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When I try saving a dict with a '.' in the key PyMongo throws an error (InvaildName) however I do see (on the Mongodb website) that keys can have '.''s in them. Why is it that pymongo won't let me save these docs? Is there an issue with them and Mongo?

James

Comment: You can use a SONManipulator - see example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name

Answer (score 12):

Where are you seeing an example of documents with "." in a key name? Those are invalid in MongoDB (hence PyMongo's restriction).

The reasoning is that we use dot notation in queries to reach inside of embedded documents.

Comment: This is no longer true in a newer MongoDB version, see the linked question above

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dot in updates and finds, but not in save/insert.