# Creating a TagRange based on sub-document shard key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm looking for advise on what I'm doing wrong or what I should be doing to Tag a sharded collection in MongoDB, which has a shard key on a sub-document field.

I'm using MongoDB 2.4 and My User collection structure looks like the blow, and is keyed on AccountId:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Account (sub-document)

  - AccountId <-- shard key
  - Field X
  - Field Y-
  - ...and so on

If call the addTagRange() helper like so:

```
sh.addTagRange("Mydb.User", {"Account.AccountId":MinKey}, {"Account.AccountId":MaxKey}, "ssd")
```

The error i get is:

```
JavaScript execution failed: can't have . in field names [Account.AccountId] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L143
```

I've tried removing quotes but that gives a similar error:

```
JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

So i'm wondering now is this possible via the helper, or do I have to edit the config db to make this work. I would have thought this was possible as MongoDB allows a shard key to be created on a sub-document in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\uff0e` to instead of dot

```
sh.addTagRange("Mydb.User", {"Account\uff0eAccountId":MinKey}, {"Account\uff0eAccountId":MaxKey}, "ssd")
```

see more: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-dollar-sign-escaping

[How to use dot in field name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name)