# Mongo database Invalid BSON field name exception

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to  follow this  [How to use dot in field name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name). But it result as the picture. There is a additional space:-

[image]

```
  protected Document setNestedField(Document doc, FieldValue parentField, String nestedFieldName, Object value, boolean concatenate) {
            if (concatenate) {
                doc.put(parentField.getSystemName() + "." + nestedFieldName, value);
            }
            else {
                doc.put(nestedFieldName, value);
            }
            return doc;
        }
```

Exception:-Invalid BSON field name photographs.inner_fields; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name photographs.inner_fields.

How can I use dot "." in field name. I have to use . as I'm using some 3rd party api and I have no option to replace to something else like [dot]. Please suggest me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MongoDB field names cannot contain the dot (.) character as it is part of dot-notation syntax, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

What third party API are you using ? Are you sure you need a dot ? Dots are commonly used when parsing JSON and your third party API should not need it.

Answer (score 2):

So, a third party api is both constructing the keys (with periods in them), AND saving that to MongoDB?

I suggest that you open a bug ticker in said API:s tracker.

If this is not the case, encode the periods somewhere in the persistence code - and decode it on the way up.