# How can I query a MongoDB field name with a . (period) in it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm digging around a MongoDB oplog, and I'm wanting to look at all operations that match the following:

```
"o" : {
    "$set" : {
        "skus.0.stock" : 1
    }
}
```

The operation in question updates an object similar to this:

```
{
    skus: [
        {
            stock: Number
        },
        {
            stock: Number
        },
    ]
}
```

The above oplog operation is `$set`ing the stock level of an object on the skus array.

The problem is when I execute `.find({"o.$set.skus.0.stock": {$exists: true}})` I get nothing back. mongo shell is expecting an object that looks like this:

```
"o" : {
    "$set" : {
        "skus" : {
            "0": {
               stock" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name), but the top answer basically just substitutes the period for a similar unicode character. In this case, the oplog has already inserted an actual period in to the field name.

Bracket notation throws an error a syntax error without quotes, and doesn't return anything with quotes (it just doesn't work.)

Comment: As per the MongoDB Limits documentation, field names should not have the "." character in them: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Comment: @James As per my question: the oplog has already inserted an actual period in to the field name. Should I file a bug report?

Comment: Updated to clarify that the oplog document reflects a $set operation on an array, not a field name on my document.

Comment: And there's the bug report https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21889 :)