# Query nested doc's field with dot in the name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

Consider such a collection:

```
> db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f969419d40c1580f2d4aa31"), "users" : { "foo@bar.com" : "baz" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9694d4d40c1580f2d4aa33"), "users" : { "baz@test.com" : "foo" } }
```

I want to find documents where `users` contains field `foo@bar.com`.
Firstly I tried

```
> db.test.find({"users.foo@bar.com": { $exists: true } })
```

But it returned nothing. Because of the dot (.) in field's name it was looking for a such a field: `users > foo@bar > com` which does not exist.
I learned that the dot in key's name can be escaped with `\u002e` so I tried

```
> db.test.find({"users.foo@bar\u002ecom": { $exists: true } })
```

But it also returns nothing. I guess that I am not escaping properly. How should I do this?

Comment: You can use an aggregation query, With `$objectToArray` operator, you can match the string `"foo@bar.com"`.

Comment: Related question: [mongodb - How to use dot in field name? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using aggregation. Try this query.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "users": {
        "$objectToArray": "$users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "users.k": "foo@bar.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "users": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$users"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/67Di-Z1pZ85)

Answer (score 0):

*Try* this one:

```
db.test.find({$expr:{$literal:{"users.foo@bar.com":{$exists:true}}}})
```

**Explanation**

- `$expr` allows us to use aggregation operators in MQL
- `$literal` returns "users.foo@bar.com" as a field (no parsing)
- $literal does not touch the inner level `$exists` still works.