# How to remove corrupted documents (. in the key) when search query fails

Tags: mongodb, corruption

So due a data problem, invalid records got into my mongoDb - they contain the period in their keys, so searching results into the error (the key must not contain....) and therefore I cannot find out which exact documents are corrupted - there are hundreds.
I cannot delete all the records but I cannot find a way how to find the corrupted ones, I cannot rely on any date/time information. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use dot in field name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429318/how-to-use-dot-in-field-name)